# facebook page_id in a tab

Tags: php, facebook

hi i am trying to get facebook page_id on a page in a tab where my application is added but i am getting error.

```
echo $_REQUEST["fb_page_id"];

Message: Undefined index: fb_page_id
```

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Comment: yes i check it but fb_sig_page_id is not working i var dump there is no params named by this i found this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas but this function also not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would var dump the `$_REQUEST` array you would see all the params available for you to use. What you want it is called `fb_sig_page_id`.